# Kernel of tensor product of maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

If $\phi:A\rightarrow C$ and $\psi:B\rightarrow D$ are homomorphisms of modules. Is it true that there exists a homomorphism $f:A\otimes B\rightarrow C\otimes D$ such that $\ker(f)=\ker(\phi)\otimes B+A\otimes \ker(\psi)$?

If this is not true in general, is in true in case of finite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: If $f=\phi\otimes\psi$ then the answer is no; the tensor product is not left exact. But over a field the answer is yes, for then the tensor product is left exact.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are flat, the expression $\mathrm{ker}(\phi)\otimes B+A\otimes\mathrm{ker}(\psi)$ becomes naturally a submodule of $A\otimes B$. But even this flatness assumption on $A$ and $B$ seems not sufficient to make the result true for $f=\phi\otimes\psi$, unless $\phi$ and $\psi$ are surjectiv (see Theorem 2.19 of these notes: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf).